deseo corregir alerta DataTables warning: table id=example
*Al querer quitar el sort en datatables me arroja la alerta de error


var  table = $('#example').DataTable({
"aoColumnDefs": [
{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 2, 3, 4 ] },
{ "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 2, 3, 4 ] }
]
});




Ya verificaste que tu table tenga el id = "example" ??

si el detalle es que ya en mi tabla establecida, quise ocultar los filtros  ⇵, pero al ejecutarlo me aroja la alerta.

Si estas usando jquery trata de meter ese código dentro de un document ready, puede ser que aun no esté cargado completamente tu table y te este ocasionando problemas.

¿Cuál fue exactamente el warning que obtuviste? Además, ¿existen las columnas 2, 3 y 4?
